# mod_rewrite to redirect to php file

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, redirect, profile

I’d like: www.example.com/username

to redirect to: www.example.com/user.php?id=username

Trying to use this mod_rewrite rule I found: RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1

I've researched this a lot and still can't get it to work. I'm beginning to think that there is a conflict somewhere...I don't know. I'm lost.

```
    <VirtualHost 111.111.111.111.:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /home/public

    <Directory /home/public>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1

     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mod_rewrite, you could use **.htaccess** to redirect 404s to a .php file that processes the URI in a similar fashion to $_GET. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `preg_match()` should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/([^/\.]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will cause all /user/username to be redirected to user.php?id=username. You can then check in your PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
  // Check if the username exists.
  // SELECT ... FROM users WHERE username = ..
}
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^user/([^/\.]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1 [L] The same thing keeps happening. The site is structured like this right now, www.example.com/user.php with a $_GET['id'] and a www.example.com/user/user.php with a $_GET['id'] for testing. Still getting a 404 page. Could it be a server setting somewhere else that I'm missing?